# Default post tab showing twice in admin bar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to re - register WordPress default post type to change the post slug to "blog" , changing permalink structure was not worked for me as it rewrite custom post types slugs also. So I used below code in my function.php

```
function my_new_default_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
    ),
    'public'  => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),
    'query_var' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
) );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
```

It worked fine and satisfied my need. But the issue is now it showing "post" item twice in the admin bar. Why is this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need to add 'show_ui' => false

```
register_post_type( 'post', array(
'labels' => array(
    'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
),
'public'  => true,
'_builtin' => false,
'_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'show_ui' => false,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),
'query_var' => false,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
```

) );

Comment: thanks buddika , you saved my day :) . you are a WordPress champ (Y)